# How can Arduino millis() - millis() equal anything other than 0?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

So I know millis() returns the time passed since the program started running, right?

Now I've run into a case where millis() is used in a delay like this:

```
long dly = millis();
while (millis() - dly < 250) {
yield();        // enough time to send response
}
```

How can the value of `millis() - dly` be more than 0?
If the point is to yield indefinitely, why would someone use a delay like this?

Comment: this is what `delay(250);` does

Comment: For the first iteration they are the same, but that while loop keeps repeating over and over and all the while millis is increasing but dly is not since it was set before the while loop was entered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am no ardunio coder, but having a look at the code:

```
long dly = millis();
while (millis() - dly < 250) {
yield();        // enough time to send response
}
```

At line 1, you define a variable that holds time passed since start then inside the while loop you retrive the current millis() until it is greater than 250ms.

Example:

```
long dly = millis(); => Say millis = 1250,
inside while loop => millis will update itself until its 1500
```

Essentially the code waits 250 miliseconds. Every time while loop runs it will return the current millis, your assumption is that it will return the old value.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you're saying. I was thinking `dly` updated as time passed as well, but it is essentially set to 0 milliseconds at program start, right?

Comment: Yes, it is set to the initial value forever

Comment: Thanks Ali Mert Cakar!